# Is inotify a one shot only solution

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, inotify

I have a program whiuch utilizes inotify.

What it does is it start watching the directory for the file being created. When it happens the program reads the content then deletes the file.

Then the user initiates an action which will create the same file again. However, inotify does not see that the file has been created a second time and the file is not processed.

Code is as follows:

```
fileCreated = false;
m_wd1 = inotify_add_watch( m_fd, "/tmp", IN_CREATE );
if( m_wd1 == -1 )
{
}
else
{
    while( true )
    {
        poll_num = poll( &fds, nfds, -1 );
        if( poll_num == -1 )
        {
            if( errno == EINTR )
                continue;
            syslog( LOG_ERR, "Fail to run poll" );
            result = 1;
        }
        else if( poll_num > 0 && ( fds.revents & POLLIN ) )
        {
            syslog( LOG_DEBUG, "Polling is successful" );
            for( ;; )
            {
                len = read( m_fd, buf, sizeof( buf ) );
                if( len == -1 && errno != EAGAIN )
                {
                    syslog( LOG_ERR, "Failure to read the inotify event" );
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }
                for( ptr = buf; ptr < buf + len; ptr += sizeof( struct inotify_event ) + event->len )
                {
                    event = (const struct inotify_event *) ptr;
                    if( event->mask & IN_CREATE )
                    {
                        std::string name( event->name );
                        if( name == "scan_results" )
                        {
                            fileCreated = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if( fileCreated || result )
                    break;
            }
        }
        if( fileCreated )
        {
            std::ifstream log( "scan_results" );
            if( log.rdstate()  & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0 )
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
            log.close();
            if( remove( "scan_results" ) != 0 )
            {
                syslog( LOG_ERR, "Failed to remove the file" );
            }
            else
            {
                syslog( LOG_DEBUG, "File deleted successfully" );
            }
        }
        fileCreated = false;
```

The while() loop runs only once. When the action happens second time I see a message "Polling is successful".

Should I add IN_MODIFY as a mask for inotify?

If it matters - this code is running inside std::thread.

Comment: Where is `fileCreated` initialized? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I updated the code. Basically this is one function.

Comment: @Igor Where are you calling `inotify_init`?  Where (why) are you populating `fds`?

Comment: You need to post a MCVE. Above there are probably no less than 50 errors just due to variables not be declared or initialized before they are used. You are missing declarations for `char buf[4096], *ptr = buf;` and `const struct inotify_event *event;` and `bool fileCreated = false;` and `int m_fd = 0, m_wd1 = inotify_add_watch (m_fd, "/tmp", IN_CREATE);` and `struct pollfd fds[] = {{m_fd, 0, 0}};` and `int poll_num = poll(fds, 1, -1 ), result = 0;` --- and that's just getting started before we reach whether you have a logic or use problem. MCVE...

Comment: See the example at [`man 7 inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, basically my question comes to this: if I call `remove()` on the file - does this mean that the watch in the directory for file creation will be removed? Because it definitely look this way.

Comment: That's better, I suspect it is as the watch is likely placed on the inode and when an inode is removed, part of the clean-up is probably removing watches. Let me find a definite answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, if it is true  can you give me some pseudocode for the workaround? If there is one...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that polling plus reading inotify is not thread-safe.

So to overcome this I had to add `inotify_init()` to every thread. So now every thread have its own inotify file descriptor. And now it looks like program works.

Thank you everybody for reading and trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have an answer, it's not a short one and it's directly from the `man 7 inotify` page in linked above in the comments. Your two pending questions from the narrowing of your questions in the comments are:

1. if I call `remove()` on the file - does this mean that the watch in the directory for file creation will be removed?; and
2. if it is true can you give me some pseudocode for the workaround?

The answer to `(1)` is *Yes*, but the watch may be recycled causing the next file/dir to which it is assigned to potentially read the pending requests for the file/dir that was closed/deleted:

> ```
> When a watch descriptor is removed by calling inotify_rm_watch(2) (or
> because a watch file is deleted or the filesystem that contains it is
> unmounted), ...
> ```

(caveat to be aware of)

> ```
>             ... any pending unread events for that watch descriptor
> remain available to read.  As watch descriptors are subsequently
> allocated with inotify_add_watch(2), the kernel cycles through the
> range of possible watch descriptors (0 to INT_MAX) incrementally.
> When allocating a free watch descriptor, no check is made to see
> whether that watch descriptor number has any pending unread events in
> the inotify queue.  Thus, it can happen that a watch descriptor is
> reallocated even when pending unread events exist for a previous
> incarnation of that watch descriptor number, with the result that the
> application might then read those events and interpret them as
> belonging to the file associated with the newly recycled watch
> descriptor.  In practice, the likelihood of hitting this bug may be
> extremely low, since it requires that an application cycle through
> INT_MAX watch descriptors, release a watch descriptor while leaving
> unread events for that watch descriptor in the queue, and then
> recycle that watch descriptor.  For this reason, and because there
> have been no reports of the bug occurring in real-world applications,
> as of Linux 3.15, no kernel changes have yet been made to eliminate
> this possible bug.
> ```

(I doubt you will ever have that many watches open)

In answer to the second question, the pseudo code would simply be to check the *mask* for:

> ```
> IN_DELETE_SELF
>         Watched file/directory was itself deleted.  (This event
>         also occurs if an object is moved to another filesystem,
>         since mv(1) in effect copies the file to the other
>         filesystem and then deletes it from the original filesys‐
>         tem.)  In addition, an IN_IGNORED event will subsequently
>         be generated for the watch descriptor.
> ```

So you can check with either the mask `IN_DELETE_SELF` or `IN_IGNORED` if the file/directory being watched is deleted.

Comment: @Jason Can you elaborate -- what part do you consider incorrect? From the comments he asked if the watch is deleted if the file/directory watched is deleted and for pseudo code. See his comment `"if I call remove() on the file - does this mean that the watch in the directory for file creation will be removed?"` In your case, the same as calling `rm -r /tmp/inotify`

Comment: The `inotify` is not set for a specific file, it is set for a directory.  That directory (`/tmp`) is not being deleted.

Comment: That's not the state of the question 2 hours ago.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, so the following scenario is in effect: I start a thread; in a thread I call inotify_add_watch() to start watching inside /tmp for creating a file called scan_results.If such file is created, I read this file and then delete this file (as you can see in the code I provided). Apparently deleting the file also removing the inotify watcher inside that directory, so the next time the file `scan_results` is created inside `/tmp` I will not receive notification. I guess I should've elaborate a little.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see exactly what is wrong with your code since you haven't provided an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but watching a directory should give you all of the subscribed events for the directory until you stop reading them.

Here's an example of using `inotify` to watch a directory...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  const int ifd = inotify_init();
  const int iwd = inotify_add_watch(ifd, "/tmp/inotify", IN_CREATE);

  char buf[4096];

  while (read(ifd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {

    const struct inotify_event* ie = (const struct inotify_event*) buf;

    std::cout << ie->name << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

```
(jason@pi) [4868] ~/tmp touch /tmp/inotify/foo
(jason@pi) [4880] ~/tmp touch /tmp/inotify/bar
(jason@pi) [4881] ~/tmp rm /tmp/inotify/foo
(jason@pi) [4882] ~/tmp touch /tmp/inotify/foo
```

---

```
(jason@pi) [4879] ~/tmp ./so
foo
bar
foo
```

Comment: you code as written will fail. If the `/tmp/inotify` file does not exist. You should start watching the directory as in my (pseudo)-code and then check if the file being created has the name `inotify`.

Comment: @Igor The code uses the directory `/tmp/inotify` instead of `/tmp` to avoid watching system files be created.  The example creates the file `foo` (`touch /tmp/inotify/foo`), creates the file `bar`, removes the file `foo`, and re-creates the file `foo` which watching the directory `/tmp/inotify` generates the two `IN_CREATE` events for.  The file `foo` is analagous to the file `scan_results` in your code.  This is how watching a directory with `inotify` works.  Do you still have questions?

Comment: no, sorry. Missed that the inotify is also a directory. But can you explain why am I receiving the event only once when I remove the file I'm interested in? Is it somehow related to polling? Because you are not doing the poll... And the example on inotify man page does use it.

Comment: @Igor The call to `poll` is unnecessary since you are only watching one directory.  You only need to read the fd returned by `inotify_init`.  I can't actually see any place where your code `break`s the while loop, but I don't think you've posted all of it.  Have you tried using a debugger or simple print statements to follow your code's execution?

Comment: this is just one function/thread. In reality I have 2 threads (and it will be more in the future) which will be watching different directories for the file presence. In terms of breaking from loop - I don't need to break. The watching/processing the file should be continuous (it is actually a daemon/service).

Comment: @Igor What I am saying is that nothing in the code you posted breaks from the `while` loop so there's no way to tell how or why your code is exiting the `while` loop.  It's more efficient to use `poll` to monitor multiple fds, but it is perfectly valid to use multiple threads to block on reading.

Comment: does this mean I should protect the polling code with the mutext/critical section? Like I said - I need the thread to continuously monitor the `/tmp` for `scan_results` file creation. In terms of debugging - all I have is logging. The service will run on the embedded device without a debugger. And I should get an event any time the file is created not the first time only.

Comment: @Igor You need to debug the code you posted above.  If you can't figure out why a piece of code is doing something specific, please post another question with an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tried it w/o success. New question is created with more code.